# how to remove this folder from gdrive - it still showing up

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api, gdrive

I had a folder with the name “CBSE 2020 2021” which keeps on poping up though i removed it, It seems it had some links ,how could i remove this folder

I am having hardtime removing this folder

[image]

Comment: You can report this issue through `?` > Send Feedback in your Drive window.

Answer (score 0):

To delete folders click the `My Drive` option which lists all the folders in your drive and then u can select whatever folder you want to delete and then right-click and select remove or click the trash can icon.

Comment: not sure if you notices my question, i tried , it could nt get removed. IT seems like this is more of a virus

Comment: is the folder is your own? or is it a shared folder?

Comment: I guess it is shared folder

Comment: If someone shared an item with you and you added that item to My Drive, removing that item just removes the item from your My Drive view. Other users can still view the item in their My Drive views. (that is, removing the item does not move the item to Trash.)

Comment: that is TRUE, that is what IS NOT happening here, it is NOT being removed from "My Drive"